# Migrate Static Blocks and multi stores from One Magento to Another

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, data-migration, static-content

What is the best way to migrate Magento Content i.e Blocks, Pages, and All content from one Magento instance to another. I have 2 Magento setups. One of which has all data and another is fresh Magento. Both have same Magento version. I do not want to migrate the complete DB as I have many junk orders/customers/products etc.. All I want to migrate is the stores, Content blocks, pages, and basically all content related data.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-import-and-export-cmsstatic-blocks-to-magento-2.html

Comment: Extensions use I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 2):

All CMS pages and static blocks are saved in the following 4 tables:

- cms_page
- cms_page_store
- cms_block
- cms_block_store

Hence, if you need to copy the content, just simply export data from these tables and then import again to your live site database.

Export:

> mysqldump -u -p database_name cms_block cms_block_store cms_page
>   cms_page_store > content.sql

Import:

> mysql -u -p database_name < content.sql

Comment: cms block/pages has reference to store tables also, won't there be any issue as the magento is fresh? Also if I dump these tables won't there be foreign key issues?

Comment: have u checked ?

Comment: I mean even if I do this, there will be issue because the tables do not include the store tables.

Comment: i have do this at my end.
Getting all cms and block content successfully :)

Comment: if you get your result please accept my answer .

Comment: store
store_group
store_website
 are some more tables I know I need to migrate, but I want t confirm if I am missing anything?

Comment: i have checked ,, all pages and block content migrated without any issue